# Specta 'should receive' code

Tags: ios, unit-testing, kiwi, specta

I'm trying to use Specta as my unit testing framework (Instead of Kiwi).
How can I test if an object receives a selector Let's say 5 times, like I do in Kiwi?

In other words, what is the equivalent to this 'Kiwi' line of code:

```
[[sut should] receive:@selector(showUpsellIfNeededForFile) withCount:5];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the functionality provided by [OCMock](http://ocmock.org), which doesn't work with Swift.

But, more importantly, do you really need to test whether a particular function is called? You've just coupled your application code to your test code.

I've used Specta and Expecta in the past and stopped using such mock tests. Rather I use it as it is meant to be used - Behavioural testing. I test that the code I am running results in a required behaviour rather than whether or not specific subsidiary methods are called during the test.